# Simulink: For Each Subsystem does not detect iteration amount

Tags: matlab, simulink

For some reason when I connect a `For Each Subsystem` to an `output block` it is unable to detect the iteration amount and will only iterate once:

[image: for each subsystem incorrect behavior]

When I connect it to something else, a `scope` in this case, it will iterate 5 times as it should:

[image: for each subsystem correct behavior]

The output connects to a `demux` with a dimension of 5 further in the simulation which in the first case fails:

> Error in port widths or dimensions. Input port 1 of
>   'control/Camera/Motor bar/Demux1' is a one dimensional vector with 5
>   elements.

Comment: May be the output port specifies a size of 1? You should set it to -1 for inherited.

Comment: The port Sample Time is -1, I've checked. So that is not the issue.

Comment: Not the sample time. Check port dimensions.

Comment: I ment the dimensions, both are -1

Comment: I am not sure whats going on. It may be a problem with dimension propagation. Try introducing signal specification blocks to set dimensions at the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output port was not the cause of the issue.

A little further on I had a `Demux` element which could not handle `a one dimensional vector with 5 elements`.

The error mentioned this properly.